# File backup with write verification

Tags: windows, gratis, backup

There is a lot of free backup software, but I'm interested in one specific feature: software should verify the file is written correctly to the storage. That is, the file should be re-read and checked against the source (or source checksum) after the write.

Additionally, it should be free, support Windows and provide encryption. And I'm going to use it with local or LAN/NAS disks.